# How to set TTreeViewItem font size and color?

Tags: delphi, treeview, firemonkey, treenode

I want to change font size in my `TTreeView`.

Code:

```
ChildTreeNode := TTreeViewItem.Create(Application);
ChildTreeNode.Parent := ParentNode;
ChildTreeNode.Font.Size := 100;
ChildTreeNode.FontColor := $DD0000DD;
```

Next I tried:
`ChildTreeNode.TextSettings.Font.Size := 50;`

But it's not working...

How can I do it?

Comment: Add this `ChildTreeNode.StyledSettings := ChildTreeNode.StyledSettings -
 [TStyledSetting.Size, TStyledSetting.FontColor];` before you setup the font.